# Can we generate Locus report from locust environment class

Tags: locust

I am using locust environment class to run load test in python

I want to generate report automatically when i run script

```
parser = argument_parser.get_parser()
p = parser.parse_args("--html=basicNew.html")

# setup Environment and Runner
env = Environment(user_classes=[Test1,Test2], events=events,parsed_options=p)
runner = env.create_local_runner()
```

Above code snippet of which i am using..Any idea how to do it